# In PHP how would you split an ECB ciphertext?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

Exactly as the Title suggest, in PHP how would you go about splitting ECB Ciphertext into component blocks?

Comment: Ive done the wikipedia reading and theory based on ECB ciphertext and component block re-ordering/shuffling.  I follow the theory, I am just unsure of how to execute, or where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just split it up with PHP's [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) or [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) functions. You'll have to know the block size.

Comment: Well what if you don't know the block size, when you are dealing with Crypto what would you typically select for a component block size.

Comment: Do you have a key for this cipher? That can be a great hint. Usually 64 bits, 128 bits, etc etc up to 4096 bits.

Comment: I would say, for what I am testing it would be rijandael-128.  So 128 bits.

Comment: Yup, 128 should be it, then.

Comment: @Murph Actually, Rijndael could be using 256 bit block ciphers. AES uses 128 bit blocks though, which is analogous to specifying `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` in mcrypt for PHP. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES because of the 256 bit blocks. This is a bit confusing as most people expect the 256 in that constant to be the key size, not the block size. The key size is certainly not directly related to the block size, so that hint may not be as good as you think it is. Block ciphers commonly go up to 256 bits, not higher as it would not make much sense.